# Java async order

Tags: java, asynchronous, async-await

I have a synchronous method that takes around 3 mins to execute due to a lot of calls inside it. So, I made those calls asynchronous but I need them to be executedd in order.

I marked those methods with @Async:

```
@Async
method1(){
   .. do something
};

@Async
method2(){
   .. do something
};

parentMethod(){
   .. some code
   method1();
   method2();
   .. some code
}
```

Both are asynchronous but I have to enable that method2 doesn't start until method1 finishes. I tried to do this but sometimes method2 starts before method1.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: What framework provides the `@Asyc` annotation?

Comment: Unless the framework does some nasty AOP trick, these method calls in parentMethod() are actually synchronous. So I second the question on what framework this is

Answer (score 0):

What about calling method2 at the end of method1 execution?

```
@Async
method1() {
   .. do something
   method2();
};

@Async
method2() {
   .. do something
};

parentMethod() {
   .. some code
   method1();
   .. some code
}
```